# Change class when scrollLeft hit end using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I looked up all the jQuery "scroll" answers, but most of them are for reaching the bottom. So I did some modify from it, but doesn't seem to work on scrollLeft. What I am trying to do is when reaching to the right-end, add a class on the "right arrow". Can someone look at the code for me, and tell me what I did wrong!!?

```js
          $(".video-menu_arrow-left").addClass("end");

            /*Video Library Arrow Click*/
            var vitem= 212;
            $(".video-menu_arrow-right").click(function () {
              $(".video-menu_list").animate({scrollLeft:"+="+vitem}, 800);
              $(".video-menu_arrow-left").removeClass("end");
            });

            $(".video-menu_arrow-left").click(function () {
              $(".video-menu_list").animate({scrollLeft:"-="+vitem}, 800);
            });

            /*Reached the last video*/
            $(".video-menu_list").on('scroll', function() {
                if($(".video-menu_list").scrollLeft() + $(".video-menu_list").innerWidth() > $(".video-menu_list")[0].scrollWidth) {
                  $(".video-menu_arrow-left").removeClass("end");
                  $(".video-menu_arrow-right").addClass("end");
                }
                if($(".video-menu_list").scrollLeft() == 0) {
                  $(".video-menu_arrow-right").removeClass("end");
                  $(".video-menu_arrow-left").addClass("end");
                }
            });
```

```css
.video-menu-container{
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.video-menu_list-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.video-menu_list {
  width: auto;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video_thumbs {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

div[class*="video-menu_arrow-"]{
  display: block;
  background: #E3E3E3;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
}

div[class*="video-menu_arrow-"].end{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="video-menu-container">
  <div class="video-menu_arrow-left">left</div>
  <div class="video-menu_list-wrap">
    <div class="video-menu_list">
      <a href="#" class="video_thumbs selected" >1</a>
      <a href="#" class="video_thumbs" >2</a>
      <a href="#" class="video_thumbs" >3</a>
      <a href="#" class="video_thumbs" >4</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="video-menu_arrow-right">right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the slider reach the last video. The first if condition never succes. That's because the sum **scrollLeft** & **innerWidth** never be more than the **scrollWidth**, but is gonna be equal. So you can easily correct your code, adding a 'more or equal(>=)' in your if condition.

And adding a **removeClass** in **your video-menu_arrow-left** click function.

I´m gonna paste all the code with corrections and some new console.log to visualize better the values of your variables.

```js
   $(".video-menu_arrow-left").addClass("end");

/*Video Library Arrow Click*/
var vitem= 212;
$(".video-menu_arrow-right").click(function () {
  $(".video-menu_list").animate({scrollLeft:"+="+vitem}, 800);
  $(".video-menu_arrow-left").removeClass("end");
});

$(".video-menu_arrow-left").click(function () {
  $(".video-menu_list").animate({scrollLeft:"-="+vitem}, 800);
  $(".video-menu_arrow-right").removeClass("end");
});

/*Reached the last video*/
$(".video-menu_list").on('scroll', function() {
    var a = $(".video-menu_list").scrollLeft();
    var b = $(".video-menu_list").innerWidth();
    var ab = a + b;
    var c = $(".video-menu_list")[0].scrollWidth;
    
    console.log(a + ' + ' + b + ' = ' + ab + ' >= ' + c);
    
    if((a + b)>= c) {
        console.log('in');
      $(".video-menu_arrow-left").removeClass("end");
      $(".video-menu_arrow-right").addClass("end");
    }

    if ($(".video-menu_list").scrollLeft() == 0) {
      $(".video-menu_arrow-right").removeClass("end");
      $(".video-menu_arrow-left").addClass("end");
    }
});
```

```css
.video-menu-container{
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.video-menu_list-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.video-menu_list {
  width: auto;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video_thumbs {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

div[class*="video-menu_arrow-"]{
  display: block;
  background: #E3E3E3;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
}

div[class*="video-menu_arrow-"].end{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="video-menu-container">
  <div class="video-menu_arrow-left">left</div>
  <div class="video-menu_list-wrap">
    <div class="video-menu_list">
      <a href="#" class="video_thumbs selected" >1</a>
      <a href="#" class="video_thumbs" >2</a>
      <a href="#" class="video_thumbs" >3</a>
      <a href="#" class="video_thumbs" >4</a>
      <a href="#" class="video_thumbs" >5</a>
      <a href="#" class="video_thumbs" >6</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="video-menu_arrow-right">right</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! And I also found out that, I cannot use flex in the "video-menu_list-wrap", other "a+b" will never bigger than "c" somehow